# Can I use my computer's network connection on my Ipod?

Tags: ipod-touch, internet, internet-sharing

I know it's possible to tether iphones to use their internet connection on the computer, but can it be used the other way? I want to use the computer's network connection on my Ipod Touch through the usb cable. Is it possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly but you can use the computer's ethernet internet connection via Wifi to the iPhone.

In that case just go to *System Preferences* > *Sharing*, then

1. Select *Internet Sharing*
2. Select *Ethernet* in the field *Share your connection from*
3. Flag *Wi-Fi* in the field *To computers using*
4. Go to *Wi-Fi Options...* and select a network SSID and a security password
5. Click *OK*
6. Flag *Internet sharing*

If you are using a pc with windows you can follow the instructions reported [here](http://mobileoffice.about.com/od/internet-sharing-tethering/ht/how-to-share-internet-connection-on-windows7.htm). Basically:

1. Go to Network Connections in your Control Panel by going to *Start* > *Control Panel* > *Network and Internet* > *Network and Sharing Center* and then click *Change adapter settings* on the menu on the left.
2. Right-click your Internet connection that you want to share (e.g., Local Area Connection) and click Properties.
3. Click the Sharing tab.
4. Check the "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection" option.

Comment: Of course, this assumes the computer has wifi.